# Must supply a value for form control at index: 1 - Error

Tags: angular, angular-reactive-forms, formarray, mat-autocomplete

I am using Reactive forms with mat autocomplete. I used autocomplete in other parts of my app but i can't figure this out. I have a formarray which adds an input every time I want to add a new sensor in my case. autocomplete works fine in my first input but when I try to add more inputs an error is shown : ***Error: Must supply a value for form control at index: 1***

HTML:

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="input-field col s10">
      <div class="form-group">
        <div formArrayName="sensors_id">
          <div *ngFor="let sensor of addHomeboxPForm.get('sensors_id')['controls']; let i = index">
            <br>
            <input formControlName="{{i}}" type="text" placeholder="Select Sensor" aria-label="Number" matInput [matAutocomplete]="auto1">
            <mat-autocomplete autoActiveFirstOption #auto1="matAutocomplete" [displayWith]="displayWith" >
              <mat-option (onSelectionChange)="updateForm($event, [sensor.sensors_id], 'sensors_id')" *ngFor="let sensor of filteredOptionsS | async" [value]="sensor.sensor_serial">
                {{sensor.sensor_serial}}
              </mat-option>
            </mat-autocomplete>
            <div class="button-left">
              <button *ngIf="addHomeboxPForm.controls.sensors_id.value.length > 1" type="button" class="fa" (click)="onRemoveItem(i)">RemoveSensor</button>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>


<div class="input-field col s2">
        <button type="button" class="btn" (click)="onAddItem()">AddSensor</button>
      </div>
```

TS:

formarray: `'sensors_id': this.fb.array([], Validators.required),`

```
  updateForm(ev: any, idd: any, componentid: any) {

    if (ev.isUserInput) {
      if (componentid === 'sensors_id') {
        this.sensorId = idd;
        this.addHomeboxPForm['controls']['sensors_id'].setValue([ev.source.value])
      }
    }
  }

  onAddItem() {
    (<FormArray>this.addHomeboxPForm.controls['sensors_id']).push(new FormControl('', Validators.required));
  }

  onRemoveItem(index: number) {
    (<FormArray>this.addHomeboxPForm.controls['sensors_id']).removeAt(index);
  }
```

I am new to this so i am sorry if i am not that clear..but i havent found a solution yet

Answer (score 0):

you fortmcontrolName should be defined in your component before you use it in the template html.

I see you have used `<input formControlName="{{i}}"` which is not valid as Angular is not able to find this formControl/field where the reactive form was declared initially.

> After you create the control in the component class, you must associate it with a form control element in the template. Update the template with the form control using the formControl binding provided by FormControlDirective included in ReactiveFormsModule.

You can read more about  [reactive forms here:](https://angular.io/guide/reactive-forms)

Hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

This error could be because you forgot to set the setValue function to an array, and instead you set it to an object (note the brackets []):

Example:
Here you would get the error. Wrong:

```
this.checkoutForm.get('items').setValue({
  itemId: ['1aa'],
  itemName: ['2aa'],
  itemDesc: ['3bb'],
  itemDone: ['', Validators.requiredTrue]
});
```

Right:

```
this.checkoutForm.get('items').setValue([{
  itemId: ['1aa'],
  itemName: ['2aa'],
  itemDesc: ['3bb'],
  itemDone: ['', Validators.requiredTrue]
}]);
```

html:

```
<div class="form-group">
        <label for="exampleInputPassword1">Items</label>
        <div class='col-sm-10' formArrayName="items">
            <div *ngFor="let item of checkoutForm.controls.items['controls']; let i=index" [formGroupName]="i">
                <a [routerLink] (click)="removeitem(i)">remove</a>
                <input class="form-control" type="text" formControlName="itemId" id=task{{i}}>
                <input class="form-control" type="text" formControlName="itemName" id="task{{i}}">
                <input class="form-control" type="text" formControlName="itemDesc" id="task{{i}}">
                <input type="checkbox" formControlname="itemDone">Mark as Done
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

While updating, use patchValue() method instead of setValue() method.

In your case, it will be -

```
    updateForm(ev: any, idd: any, componentid: any) {

    if (ev.isUserInput) {
      if (componentid === 'sensors_id') {
        this.sensorId = idd;
        this.addHomeboxPForm['controls']['sensors_id'].patchValue([ev.source.value])
      }
    }
  }

  onAddItem() {
    (<FormArray>this.addHomeboxPForm.controls['sensors_id']).push(new FormControl('', Validators.required));
  }

  onRemoveItem(index: number) {
    (<FormArray>this.addHomeboxPForm.controls['sensors_id']).removeAt(index);
  }
```